# New beta site design has unreadable annotation indicators on accounts

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, annotations

The new beta site theme has fairly hard-to-read annotation counters on user profiles:

[image]

Can we make the text white?

[image]

Comment: Someone's been a *bad* person.

Answer (score 5):

The same problem occurs with flags in the mod dashboard, where I fixed it<sup>1</sup> with the following CSS override (be sure to do this only on beta sites; it'll mess up designs on some graduated sites):

```
/* flag color */
.supernovabg.mod-flag-indicator {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

I stuck this in a Stylish override that I was [already using for other adjustments to the new beta theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251475/162102).

I chose yellow background and black text for old time's sake, but you can do whatever you like.

After making this change for flags I noticed that it also affected the annotation indicators that you're asking about.  Even though this is the "mod flag indicator", it affects annotations and *not* flags on the user profile pages (but flags on the mod dashboard).

<sup>1</sup> Except for one occurrence in a tab header, which -- while indicating flags -- seems to be using a bounty UI element.  Or something weird like that.  I'm just ignoring that.

Answer (score 4):

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), probably with the [new site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232) a while ago:

[image]

However, upon hovering over it, the text becomes blue again. (This is a problem on all sites, not just beta sites. I've opened [a new ticket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352573/295232) for that.)