# Is it possible to make the annotation and flag counters on profiles colorblind friendly?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, profile-page, moderator-tools, accessibility

I have a heck of a hard time identifying whether a user has annotations or flagged posts on their account when looking at the profile page and only one is present. There is an [older post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251547/new-beta-site-design-has-unreadable-annotation-indicators-on-accounts) asking for a text color change, but the problem for me is the background.

When both are there, I can see the contrast in the colors well enough. But when only one is there, I cannot tell by looking at it which type of counter it is without mousing over it. On the desktop, this is annoying but not impossible. When using a mobile device though, it's not as easy to get tooltips to pop up.

Is it possible to get a more colorblind-accessible palette for these two counters? [Light blue/dark blue](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Paired&n=3) for example, or even changing the annotations to a more yellow-y color of orange (at least, I think it's supposed to be orange?) and the flagged posts to a more red-y color of red.

While a userscript is possible, I can't use them at work or on mobile, so a native correction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently using a userscript to work around this, and would love to see a native solution.  As part of that native solution, I very much want to see flags go back to black text on yellow background, like it used to be before the orange invasion.  At the size that flags show on the mod dashboard, I *cannot read* the current white text on orange background.  The contrast for the colors they chose there is terrible.

Comment: If it's possible, changing the shape of the border would be another solution.

Comment: @ChrisF If changing shape is also possible, then I'd rather see both a shape and color change. As many different ways to identify something at once is great because you never know what accessibility challenges are out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marked this as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) because we don't have a timeline yet for when we will prioritize this. There have been discussions regarding a larger initiative to do an accessibility audit, but this isn't yet a concrete roadmap item. I have tagged a designer to see if this specific request is a quick fix or something more involved.

Comment: Did the meaning of status tags change again? Last I checked, status-declined was being used for anything that couldn't fit in the roadmap.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I guess status-deferred means "we want to do this but not in the near future" while status-declined means now (since the recent ticket smash) either "we don't want to do this" or "we don't know if we want to do this or not so it's still status-review but we want to remove the status-review tag from it". So concretely "deferred" means more commitment to the feature than the second meaning of the new "declined".

Comment: @Wrigglenite As per the extended tag wiki for the deferred tag, which has been in place for years: *A feature request or bug with this tag is something that has been evaluated as positive on potential, but is not present in the current work timeline.* This is the correct tag here.

Comment: @Sonic I'm obviously referring to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361140/370674