# Number of annotations hard to read when hovering

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, moderator-tools

When hovering over the number of annotations for a user, the (white) text becomes blue and hard to read:

[image]

It's better to keep it white, just like the number of flags received:

[image]

Comment: @Mari-Lou Different situation, that bug was fixed.

Comment: @M  Retracted close vote as soon as I realised. It would, however, be worth pointing out in *this* post the differences between the two reports.

Comment: Oddly, it repros *only* on the annotations, not on the flagged posts or CM contacts. The reason this is odd is because the code and styling for all 3 of these elements are apparently identical. The proximate cause is that the `.supernovabg` style doesn't have a foreground color defined. The *real* root cause is that Stacks is a regression from 25 years ago in terms of web design, and the only way to "fix" it is to add `!important` hacks on top of hacks.